# Bipartite question

Tags: graph-theory

Let $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$, where $a\geq b$, and let $G_{a,b}$ be the graph where $V(G_{a,b})$ is the set of all $b$-subsets of $[a]$, and two subsets $M$, $N$ are adjacent if and only if $\lvert M\bigcap N\lvert=1$.

1. What is the number of vertices and edges in $G_{a,b}$?
2. Prove that when $a\geq 3b-3 > 0$, $G_{a,b}$ is not bipartite.

Can someone help me with this please? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  Two thing: 1) This site has MathJax enabled, so that you can nicely typeset mathematics.  This makes it MUCH more readable; see the edit I made to your post, and also [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for more info.  Second:  what have you tried?  Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: Hint 1: There are $\binom{a}{b}$ ways of choosing a $b$-subset of $a$ element set. If $|M|=|N|=b$ and $|M\cap N|=1$, $N$ contains precisely $(b-1)$ elements out of those which are not in $M$.  Hint 2: Assuming the given inequality, can you produce three $b$-subsets, every two of which have one element in common? (having a cycle of length 3 proves the graph can not be bipartite)

Comment: Thank you. I was just editing the text, since I realized I forgot the $ $. I have tried to look at similar problems to this, but I still can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\order}[1]{\lvert #1\rvert}$
Here are some hints:

## The size of the vertex/edge sets:

The size of the vertex set should be immediate from the definition.  For the size of the edgeset, remember that the number of edges is half the total degree of the graph; perhaps it is easier to count the degree of a specific subset than to outright try to count edges?

Suppose that you have a fixed set $N\subseteq[a]$, $\order{N}=b$. The sets $M$ such that there is an edge between $N$ and $M$ are precisely those $M$ which intersect $N$ in exactly one point. If you wanted to count these, you could do so by noting that such $M$ must consist of 1 element that is in $N$, and $b-1$ elements that are in $[a]\setminus N$. Does this suggest a counting formula?

## Proving the graph is not bipartite:

Here, it suffices to show that you have a *triangle* - that is, three sets $M,N,P\subseteq[a]$, all of size $b$, which are all connected. In other words, we must have the size of all the intersections $M\cap N$, $M\cap P$, and $N\cap P$ being exactly 1.  Can you come up with such sets?

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll work on this and report back.

Comment: I think I got it now. Thank you very much!

Comment: My pleasure!  I'm glad that you've got it figured out. And if my answer was helpful, please consider accepting it.

Comment: Alternatively, now that you have figured it out, you can write it up and post it as an answer, yourself.