# Proving that a graph is NOT bipartite

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

For any $n,k\in \mathbb{N}$ where $n\geq k$ let $G_{n,k}$ be the graph where $V(G_{n,k})$ is the set of all $k$-subsets of $[n]$, and two subsets $S,T$ are adjacent iff $|S\cap T|=1$.

Prove that when $n\geq 3k-3 > 0$, $G_{n,k}$ is not bipartite.

This is homework, so I don't want a full solution, just some hints. I have already derived that the number of vertices is ${n \choose k}$ and the number of edges, when there are edges, is $\frac{k^2\binom{n-k}{k}}{2}$. Is this correct? How can I proceed?

Comment: See [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/431065/bipartite-question/) from earlier today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Find a triangle in $G_{n,k}$; this proves it's not bipartite.

Answer (score 1):

There are, as you say, $\binom{n}k$ vertices. If $K\subseteq[n]$ is a vertex, there are $k\binom{n-k}{k-1}$ vertices adjacent to $K$: there are $k$ ways to choose the one element of $[n]$ that the vertex shares with $K$, and there are $\binom{n-k}{k-1}$ ways to choose the other $k-1$ elements of the other vertex. There are $\binom{n}k$ ways to choose $K$, and each edge is counted twice, so the number of edges should be

$$\frac12\binom{n}kk\binom{n-k}{k-1}=\frac{k}2\binom{n}{k,k-1,n-2k+1}\;.$$

As a quick check, you can verify by brute force that $G_{4,2}$ has $12$ edges, not the $2$ that your formula gives it.

HINT: Note that $3k-3=3(k-1)$, so if $n\ge 3k-3>0$, you can find pairwise disjoint, non-empty $(k-1)$-sets $A,B,C\subseteq[n]$. And a bipartite graph cannot contain a copy of $K_3$.

Comment: What does commas in a binomial expression mean?

Comment: @user54609: That’s a [*multinomial coefficient*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem). If $a_1+\ldots+a_k=n$, then $$\binom{n}{a_1,\ldots,a_k}=\frac{n!}{a_1!\cdot\ldots\cdot a_k!}\;.$$ Thus, the ordinary binomial coefficient is the special case with $k=2$.